# How can I get the all of the prefixes of data in here

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

sdf = pd.read_csv('customers.csv')
skuList = sdf['sku'].values.tolist()
prefixedSku = {s[:2] for s in skuList}
print(prefixedSku)
```

I want to store the first 2 letters of all data in `prefixedSku` but there is showing 3 results only...

```
{'S2', 'B1', 'S1'}
```

I'm expected that the output would be like this. 
    `{'S2', 'B1', 'S1' ... , 'S2' , 'S1' , 'S1' , 'B1' , ' S2' ...}` 
Actually, I have many data which is related to S1,B1 and S2. 
Here is the similar example of the  **customers.csv**

```
account  sku
0001     B1-20000
0002     S2-77896
        .
        .
        .
1000     S1-99999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly you want a list of prefixes that correspond to your rows. Your code is correct if you switch your set comprehension to a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

sdf = pd.read_csv('customers.csv') 
skuList = sdf['sku'].values.tolist()
# Changed {} to []
prefixedSku = [s[:2] for s in skuList]
print(prefixedSku)
```

Edit: changed dict to set

Comment: @dsbailey that aint a dict comprehension but a set comprehension. A set can only have unique value, hence the duplicates were removed.